# How to change font size of navigationPage in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I have a Xamarin.Form project.
I want to change the font size of navigationBar in Win phone 8.1.
Here is my code.

```
public partial class App: Application
{
  public App()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage))
    {
      BarBackgroundColor = Color.Red,
      //BarFontSize = "Large"???
    };
  }
}
```

How can I change fontsize of navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Render
  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22825/how-to-change-title-font-for-navigation-bar

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/XamarinFormsToolbarCustomFont

You can also use this plugin

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/XamarinFormsToolbarCustomFont

Comment: I am finding a solution due to Win Phone